# Send from Twisted client to Twisted server, only this one way

Tags: python, networking, twisted

I want to use Twisted to rebuild the communication part of an existing application. This application does send data from the client to the server, only this way round, the server does not send anything.

How do I accomplish this with the event-driven concept of Twisted? I currently use the `connectionMade` method of `Protocol`, but I don't think this is the right way.

```
class Send(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        while True:
            data = queue.get()
            self.transport.write(data + "\n")
            self.transport.doWrite()
```

I'm pretty sure, this is *not* the way to do that. ;-)

**Addition**:
My problem is, I cannot imaging what event to use for this. I think the `connectionMade` event is not the right one, but I will never reach any other event than `connectionLost` in my case, because the server does not send anything to the client. Should I change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is definitely not the right way to do that.  Never, ever call `doWrite`.

The problem here is that I bet `queue.get()` just blocks until there is some data.  If possible, use a non-blocking means of message passing rather than threads.  For example, have your thread just `callFromThread` to your `Send` protocol to do something.

But, assuming a blocking 'get' call, something like this might work :

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.threads import deferToThread

class Send(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.qget()

    def qget(self, data=None):
        if data is not None:
            self.transport.write(data)
        deferToThread(queue.get).addCallback(self.qget)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538617/http-download-very-big-file/1657324#1657324 talks about the dangers of loops in Twisted code, and also covers producers/consumers which might also be helpful to the questioner.

Comment: Yes, it sounds reasonable not to use loops nor blocking calls in Twisted events, this would make the event-driven framework senseless.

Comment: why should you never call `doWrite`?

Comment: `doWrite` is the method that gets called from the reactor, when it is time to write some data out.  It means that the underlying file descriptor is ready to be written to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an another question which uses UDP / Multicast to talk between server and client

- [UDP client and server with Twisted Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632210/udp-client-and-server-with-twisted-python/3632240#3632240)

I would also suggest some additional reading and examples from the twisted documentation it self.

- http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327